# SQL comparison functions/operators on Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I need to run the following query on a Django model:

```
SELECT *
FROM app_model
WHERE GREATEST(field1, fixed_value) < LEAST(field2, another_fixed_value)
```

Is there any way for me to run this query without resorting to the raw() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least avoid `raw` by using `extra`.  I don't think the ORM otherwise exposes `GREATEST` or `LEAST`.

In theory you could break down your constraint into its different possibilities and `or` them together:

```
mymodel.objects.filter(Q(field1__gt=fixed_value and field2__lt=another_fixed_value and field1__lt=field2) | \
                       Q(field1__lte=fixed_value and field2__lt=another_fixed_value and field2__gt=fixed_value) | \
                       Q(field1__gt=fixed_value and field2__gte=another_fixed_value and field1__lt=another_fixed_value) | \
                       Q(field1__lte=fixed_value and field2__gte=another_fixed_value and fixed_value < another_fixed_value))
```

Except obviously you wouldn't actually include that `and fixed_value < another_fixed_value`.  If they're literally fixed and you know them when writing the code, you'd just make the first two comparisons - if you don't know them, only build the last Q object and or it into the query if necessary.

That said, that's horrible and I think `extra` is a much better choice.

```
mymodel.objects.extra(where=['GREATEST(field1, fixed_value) < LEAST(field2, another_fixed_value)'])
```

Comment: Thanks! The extra() method is what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

```
   Model.objects.filter(id__gt=4)
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id > 4;
```

less than

```
Model.objects.filter(id__lt=4)
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id < 4;
```